# Custom TabRow in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I use TabRow and I have two questions:

- Is it possible to remove a line that is wide the entire width screen?
- How Can  I bring the buttons together (reduce space between them)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the line under the tabs just set an empty divider by passing `divider = {}`.

To make the tabs fill the space available in the `TabRow` (therefore without empty spaces), just do **not set a specific size** to the Tabs, the following example works as you ask.

```kotlin
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val titles = listOf("TAB 1", "TAB 2")
Column {
    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = state, divider = {}) {
        titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(title) },
                selected = state == index,
                onClick = { state = index }
            )
        }
    }
}
```